# Multiple If Conditions Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, shift-register

I have a project which requires me to read if the input is "HIGH".
I have 15 inputs (switches), and each input has its own output (LED). I am using a Shift Register to control its inputs and outputs.

My current code looks like this (4 inputs and 4 outputs, it works though...):

```
#include "SPI.h"
#include "MFRC522.h"
#include "rgb_lcd.h"
#include <Wire.h>

#define SS_PIN 17
#define RST_PIN 7

int counter = 0;
int lock = 100;

MFRC522 rfid(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);
rgb_lcd lcd;
MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key;

// Define Pins
int SHIFTIN_LATCH = 22;
int SHIFTIN_DATA = 23;
int SHIFTIN_CLOCK = 21;
int numberToDisplay = 0;

#define SHIFTOUT_DATA  18
#define SHIFTOUT_LATCH  19
#define SHIFTOUT_CLOCK  20

//Define variables to hold the data
//for each shift register.
//starting with non-zero numbers can help
//troubleshoot
byte keySlotID[15] = {
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
byte keyInsert[15] = {
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
byte keyReg[10] = {
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; // amt of reg.

void setup() {
  //start serial
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //define pin modes
  pinMode(SHIFTIN_LATCH, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SHIFTIN_CLOCK, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SHIFTIN_DATA, INPUT);

  pinMode(SHIFTOUT_DATA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SHIFTOUT_LATCH, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SHIFTOUT_CLOCK, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SPI.begin();
  rfid.PCD_Init();
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

void KeyID(){
  // Key slot indicator.
  keySlotID[0] = (keyReg[0] & 0x1E) >> 1;
  keySlotID[1] = (((keyReg[1] & 0x03) << 3) | ((keyReg[0] & 0xE0) >> 5)) >> 1;
  keySlotID[2] = (keyReg[1] & 0x78) >> 3;
  keySlotID[3] = (keyReg[2] & 0x0F);
  // Key inserted indicator.
  keyInsert[0] = (keyReg[0] & 0x01);
  keyInsert[1] = (keyReg[0] & 0x20) >> 5;
  keyInsert[2] = (keyReg[1] & 0x04) >> 2; // X
  keyInsert[3] = (keyReg[1] & 0x80) >> 7; // X
}

void registerWrite(byte data1, byte data2) {
  digitalWrite(SHIFTOUT_LATCH, LOW);
  delay(10);
  shiftOut(SHIFTOUT_DATA, SHIFTOUT_CLOCK, MSBFIRST, data2);  
  shiftOut(SHIFTOUT_DATA, SHIFTOUT_CLOCK, MSBFIRST, data1);
  digitalWrite(SHIFTOUT_LATCH, HIGH);
  delay(10);
}



void LedIFs() {

  if (keyInsert[0] == 0 && keyInsert[1] == 0 && keyInsert[2] == 0 && keyInsert[3] == 0) {
    registerWrite(0xFF,0);
  }
  else if (keyInsert[0] == 0 && keyInsert[1] == 0 && keyInsert[2] == 0 && keyInsert[3] == 1) {
    registerWrite(0x40,0);
  }
  else if (keyInsert[0] == 0 && keyInsert[1] == 0 && keyInsert[2] == 1 && keyInsert[3] == 0) {
    registerWrite(0x10,0);
  }
  else if (keyInsert[0] == 0 && keyInsert[1] == 0 && keyInsert[2] == 1 && keyInsert[3] == 1) {
    registerWrite(0x50,0);
  }
  else if (keyInsert[0] == 0 && keyInsert[1] == 1 && keyInsert[2] == 0 && keyInsert[3] == 0) {
    registerWrite(0x04,0);
  }
  else if (keyInsert[0] == 0 && keyInsert[1] == 1 && keyInsert[2] == 0 && keyInsert[3] == 1) {
    registerWrite(0x44,0);
  }
  else if (keyInsert[0] == 0 && keyInsert[1] == 1 && keyInsert[2] == 1 && keyInsert[3] == 0) {
    registerWrite(0x14,0);
  }
  else if (keyInsert[0] == 0 && keyInsert[1] == 1 && keyInsert[2] == 1 && keyInsert[3] == 1) {
    registerWrite(0x54,0);
  }
  else if (keyInsert[0] == 1 && keyInsert[1] == 0 && keyInsert[2] == 0 && keyInsert[3] == 0) {
    registerWrite(0x01,0);
  }
  else if (keyInsert[0] == 1 && keyInsert[1] == 0 && keyInsert[2] == 0 && keyInsert[3] == 1) {
    registerWrite(0x41,0);
  }
  else if (keyInsert[0] == 1 && keyInsert[1] == 0 && keyInsert[2] == 1 && keyInsert[3] == 0) {
    registerWrite(0x11,0);
  }
  else if (keyInsert[0] == 1 && keyInsert[1] == 0 && keyInsert[2] == 1 && keyInsert[3] == 1) {
    registerWrite(0x51,0);
  }
  else if (keyInsert[0] == 1 && keyInsert[1] == 1 && keyInsert[2] == 0 && keyInsert[3] == 0) {
    registerWrite(0x05,0);
  }
  else if (keyInsert[0] == 1 && keyInsert[1] == 1 && keyInsert[2] == 0 && keyInsert[3] == 1) {
    registerWrite(0x45,0);
  }
  else if (keyInsert[0] == 1 && keyInsert[1] == 1 && keyInsert[2] == 1 && keyInsert[3] == 0) {
    registerWrite(0x15,0);
  }
  else if (keyInsert[0] == 1 && keyInsert[1] == 1 && keyInsert[2] == 1 && keyInsert[3] == 1) {
    registerWrite(0x55,0);
  }
}

void loop() {

  //Pulse the latch pin:
  //set it to 1 to collect parallel data
  digitalWrite(SHIFTIN_LATCH,1);
  //set it to 1 to collect parallel data, wait
  delay(1);
  //set it to 0 to transmit data serially  
  digitalWrite(SHIFTIN_LATCH,0);

  //while the shift register is in serial mode
  //collect each shift register into a byte
  //the register attached to the chip comes in first
  keyReg[0] = ~shiftIn(SHIFTIN_DATA, SHIFTIN_CLOCK);
  keyReg[1] = ~shiftIn(SHIFTIN_DATA, SHIFTIN_CLOCK);
  keyReg[2] = ~shiftIn(SHIFTIN_DATA, SHIFTIN_CLOCK);

  LedIFs();
  KeyID();
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that it would be too long for me to write down 15 `KeyInsert`s. That would mean I have to write about or close to 200,000 lines of code...

Comment: some code wasn't added as it is of no relations to this part of the code.

Comment: What are you trying to do **EXACTLY**?

Comment: Just Read the Inputs and if the input is high, output is high. It would've been easier if i don't need to use a shift register but i have to , to save pins. Im currently doing a project, a 15 lock project.

Comment: Can you please add your circuit diagram.

Comment: Could you please describe KeyInsert, KeyReg and KeySlotID.

Comment: Key insert is the switch. KeyReg is thE SHIFTIN register. Key Slot ID is smtg unrelated, you can just ignore that.

Comment: May I respectfully suggest you read up on how to write loops? This should be achievable in a dozen lines of code.

Comment: If each input represents a single bit in the output then it's about 3 lines: `uint16 output=0; for (int i=0;i<16;i++) output |= keyInsert[i]<<i;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume value that will be stored into "keyInsert" are either "1" or "0". Therefore, its a waste to declare them as an array byte

```
byte keyInsert[15] = {
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

It means that you will have 15 * 8 bytes variable, and its overkill.
it will be much simpler if you declare it as

```
uint16_t keyInsert;
```

Which have 16 bits data (2 bytes).
in your code, you can implement it by doing

```
void LedIFs() {
if (keyInsert == 0x0001) registerWrite(0xFF,0); else 
if (keyInsert == 0x0002) registerWrite(......)......
......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will be using `digitalRead`s and `digitalWrite`s but just follow this logic:

```
int state[num_of_switch_that_you_have];

for(int i=0; i<num_of_switch_that_you_have; i++)
{
  //buttonPins is the pin to which all your buttons are connected to in an array
  state[i] = digitalRead(buttonPins[i]);

  //leds is the pin to which all your leds are connected to in an array
  digitalWrite(leds[i], state[i]);
}
```

Try to follow this logic while using your shift registers. Sorry if I don't have a full code with shift registers for you, I'm not really good with them!

If you need any more details, please comment, I'll be happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite get the logic of your `keyInsert[]` array. Why don't you
use a binary number (e.g. `uint16_t`, which is 16 bits) instead of an
array of zeros and ones? Also, half of the lines of the output shift
register seem essentially unused.

If I understand correctly, you want to simplify `LedIFs()` in order to
handle many bits with few lines of code. Examining your current
implementation, it appears that you are writing to the output register
the very same bits you have in `keyInsert[]`, only in different
positions. Instead of testing every possible combination, it would be
much simpler to just move the bits into their appropriate positions:

- `keyInsert[0]` becomes bit 0 (i.e. least significant) of the first
  argument of `registerWrite()`
- `keyInsert[1]` becomes bit 2 (it's weight is 2<sup>2</sup> = 0x04)
- `keyInsert[2]` is bit 4 (weight: 2<sup>4</sup> = 0x10)
- `keyInsert[3]` is bit 6 (weight: 2<sup>6</sup> = 0x40)

This is done using bit shifts, and joining the bits with the `|`
bitwise-or operator:

```
void LedIFs() {
    byte val = keyInsert[0] << 0
             | keyInsert[1] << 2
             | keyInsert[2] << 4
             | keyInsert[3] << 6;
    if (val == 0) val = 0xff;
    registerWrite(val, 0);
}
```

Notice that `<< 0` has no effect: it is here only because it looks nicer
(more symmetric, easier to read) this way. The compiler will optimize
out this operation anyway. Also, the case when all the bits are zero is
special, since you are writing 0xff instead of zero.

If I were you, what I would do is store the information in `keyInsert[]`
as a single number with the bits already at their correct position. Then
I would write

```
uint16_t keyInsert;

//...

static inline void LedIFs() {
    registerWrite(keyInsert ? keyInsert : 0xff, 0);
}
```